# ASN1_get_object:too long

Tags: openssl

If I call openssl like this:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify test.pubkey -signature test.seckey test.data
```

I get this message:

```
...ASN1_get_object:too long:asn1_lib.c:145:
...ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:tasn_dec.c:1325:
...ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:390:Type=DSA_SIG
```

I guess a file is not valid.

Which of the three files (test.pubkey, test.seckey, test.data) could be the invalid file?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww yes you are right. I am using openssl, I am calling it via subprocess from Python, but this is not relevant in this question. Unfortunately I have no clue which stackexchange site could match to this question.

Comment: Looks like a development question to me.